# How to use a testenv for every env except one in tox?

Tags: python, pytest, tox

I have the following `tox.ini` file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py{27,34,35,36,37},flake8

[testenv]
changedir = {toxworkdir}/{envname}
deps =
    pytest-cov
    pytest
setenv =
    COVERAGE_FILE = {toxinidir}/.coverage.{envname}
commands =
    pytest {toxinidir}/tests --cov=SOME_DIRECTORY --cov-report=html:{toxinidir}/coverage_html_report/{envname} {posargs}

[testenv:flake8]
basepython = python3
skip_install = true
deps = flake8
commands = flake8 src tests

[flake8]
ignore: F401,E402,W503,W291,E501,W605
```

I would like the first `testenv` to be run only for `py{27,34,35,36,37}` and not `flake8`. I tried doing `[testenv:py{27,34,35,36,37}]` but it does change the behavior of the commands inside that `testenv` (the pytest command is not run).

How can I specify that the code currently in `[testenv]` to be run only for `py{27,34,35,36,37}`?